# Whats wrong with Watcher in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio

I got some strange behaviour of my android studio.
On my "watcher" window i have different result from that there really is.
The Watcher does not want to show static final string from a Preferences class, but from the code it looks fine.
Whats wrong?
I attached a video demostration

If i evatule in watcher

```
Preferences.KEY_PREF_PAY_BUTTONS
```

i got null

From the App and from sources i can see that this thing is static final and it unit to non null string.

http://recordit.co/dGo2xLqG8o

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_"

Comment: Can you please add your imports?

Comment: True. I had import java.util.prefs.Preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you cant name your Class "Preferences" it compiles with no error but then debugging it tryes to get from "java.util.prefs.Preferences"
Sorry for disturbing. Hope this was help someone.

Comment: That only will happen if the imported class was the wrong class. Otherwise, Java use the full package name to disambiguate. java.util.prefs.Preferences != com.domain.appname.example.Preferences